# Rails 4: Stop redirect after create or update form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

How can I **not redirect** to an other view after creating or updating a form using `remote: true` in Rails?

```
//route
resources :pictures


// action
def create
  @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @picture.save
      #format.html { redirect_to @picture, notice: 'Picture was successfully created.' }
      #format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @picture }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      #format.json { render json: @picture.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


// view
<%= form_for(@picture, remote: true, :authenticity_token => true, html: { multipart: true } ) do |f| %>

    [...]

<%= f.submit %>
```

If I just remove the redirect function I get the error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

[image: error image]

Comment: can you post your action code here?

Comment: is your `.js`-file in your view named `create.js.erb` ?

Comment: Yes. But its blank

Answer (score 1):

**This is due to response format**

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @data.save
   format.js
   #you need to remove format.html form here just keep format.js
  else
   format.html { render :new}
  end
end
```

Comment: Do not work. It redirect anymay with the error: ActionController::UnknownFormat

Comment: you need to specify remote: => true and create a file in view folder named create.js.erb

Comment: did you removed new.html.erb ? keep both file use format.js not format.js

Comment: No, I dont remove any fale, just commented the code of redirect

Comment: View comment above just use format.js not format.json but you can keep both

Comment: Yeah, I try that. Just format.js It still redirect and get the error: ActionController::UnknownFormat

Comment: Look you are using remote: :remote instead of remote: true and no necessary to use remote: true in submit button. Simple error man!

Comment: Thanks! Code updated, look above. But when I submit the form, it still redirect to /pictures (index action) and return the error: ActionController::UnknownFormat

Comment: Is there is create.js.erb file in app/views/pictures/

Comment: No, this file dont exist

Comment: Create the file. The redirection error is due to absence of that file.

Comment: Should create a blank file? Just tried that and the error persist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119027/discussion-between-pradeep-sapkota-and-fernando-aureliano). click the link

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use 2 options (remote: true, multipart: true) which can't work together. If you want to use AJAX for upload files, you should try this awesome GEM [remotipart](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart)